# Registration form with roles MVC3, Error: ViewData item is of type "system.sting" must be "IEnumerable<selectlistitem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ienumerable

I'm using MVC3 with razor and I wanna make a registration form where I can choose role with a dropdownlist.

I get the roles in the dropdown list and all that but when i click submit i get:

The `ViewData` item that has the key 'Role' is of type `System.String` but must be of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

My code

Model:

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "Select role: ")]
    public String Role { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem item;
        foreach (String role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
        {
            item = new SelectListItem{ Text = role, Value = role};
            list.Add(item);
        }

        ViewBag.roleList = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)list;
        return View();
    }
```

My post controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

My view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, ViewBag.roleList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role)

        </div>
```

When I use the debugger to check my code, in the controller when I look on the parameter model and at `model.Role` I see the right String.
Does anyone know any solution to my problem?

Comment: I've just tried this code (with a few modifications to replace the GetAllRoles routine, to add the submit button to the form and to remove the membership lines from the post) and it worked fine.  At the end, are you saying that this works in debug mode but doesn't when you run it in release?

Comment: no it don't work in debug mode but the model gets the right string for it but when i do model.Role it i get the error message.

Comment: So are you saying that you can run the code and it will display the drop down box in the Register View? From what I gather you can select a value in the drop down box, click submit and break at the beginning of your post action.  You can see that the model contains the selected value?  So then if you continue to execute the code after this break then the error occurs?  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It break at Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role);

Comment: Sorry about that but i just figured that out, it shows the error message in the view at @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, ViewBag.roleList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) but it really triggers in the controller

Comment: If the error is occurring in AddUserToRole() then I think the next move is to add the code of AddUserToRole() to the question.

Comment: First, that method comes with the roles class from Microsoft it takes two Strings as argument, so i don't think the problem is there. Second, i get the same error if i just use the model.Role to something else. You don't know any other way to do the stuff i wanna perform?

Comment: I didn't realise that it was part of the web security namespace (I incorrectly assumed you had defined it as you had defined the Role property).  Its difficult to say what is causing the issue as you say it breaks at the AddUserToRole line but nothing seems to be incorrect with your call here.  Anyway, I hope to manage to get this issue resolved.  Sorry I could not be of any further help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your POST action you are not repopulating the `roleList` in the `ViewBag` in the case when you redisplay the view:

```
...
// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form

// but before redisplaying the form ensure that we have populated the 
// ViewBag.roleList that this form depends on
ViewBag.roleList = ... same stuff as your GET action
return View(model);
```

This being said I would recommend you to get rid of `ViewBag` and add the `RoleList` property to your view model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Select role: ")]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList
    {
        get
        {
            return Roles
                .GetAllRoles()
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x,
                    Text = x
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var model = new RegisterModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);
        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Role);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view:

```
@model RegisterModel
...

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, Model.RoleList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role)
</div>
```

No more ViewBag => no problems.

Comment: Thanks that helped, but i had to use a foreach to fill the RoleList, the .select gave me an error.

Comment: Although I'm 4 years behind .... I implemented the above code and and got error "Unable to connect to DB"