# Creating Checkboxes for Asp.Net Roles in Razor with MVC4

Tags: razor, html-helper, roles, asp.net-mvc-4, checkboxfor

The answer in the following post:

[Registration form with roles MVC3, Error: ViewData item is of type "system.sting" must be "IEnumerable<selectlistitem>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741869/registration-form-with-roles-mvc3-error-viewdata-item-is-of-type-system-sting)

Worked for me great. However, how would this change, if I had to assign an user to a list of Asp .Net Roles?

I want to be able to iterate through a list of Roles available and render checkboxes, and how do I see what roles the user is assigned to when they click update from the Model? (I hope this question makes sense).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it without using the html helpers.  **I am still looking for an answer with HTML helpers** :).

Model

```
    public class RolesModel
    {
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public string[] Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Code To Launch the View

```
    public Action Result ShowRoles()
    {
      model.Roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
    }
```

Razor View

```
    @foreach (string role in Model.Roles)
    {
      <input type="checkbox" name="Roles" value="@role" checked="@Roles.IsUserInRole(@role)"       />@role
    }
```

Controller Code To Update the View

```
    public ActionResult AccountManagement()
    {
      if (Roles.GetRolesForUser().Length > 0 )
        Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(model.Email, Roles.GetRolesForUser());

      if (model.Roles != null && model.Roles.Length > 0)
        Roles.AddUserToRoles(model.Email, model.Roles);
    }
```

As always if there is a cleaner/better way of doing it, please let me know.

Comment: i am new to this forum, is there anything wrong in saying "thanks in advance"? ( i am still learning :))

Comment: Salutations and taglines are frowned upon. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).